# How to block ports (in Linux) based on the IP used to connect?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, centos5

I'd like to block specific ports based on the IP used to connect to my (Linux) dedicated server.

For example, I have the following IP's assigned to my dedicated server:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

The first IP (192.168.0.1) would be used specifically for administrative purposes, such as SSH, FTP, WHM, and cPanel. This means that I would want things such as port 80 and port 443 blocked.

Then for the other two IP addresses (192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3), I'd want to block the following ports: 21, 22, 2083, 2087, etc. This is because those IP addresses would only be used to serve websites, and should not be allowing access to "administrative ports".

I'd assume I'd have to use some sort of `iptables` rule, but I'm not exactly sure what.

Also, if it matters, I'm using `CENTOS 5`.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my question, could you please take the time to state why I deserved the downvote? Thanks.

Comment: `man iptables` or use Google. I don't find this stuff (e.g. 'chains' in iptables) very easy but I do find the answers that way.  BTW I think it's better and easier to just block all incoming traffic (rule 1) and then open port 80 (rule 2).

Comment: My guess is that the downvote is because you didn't explain where exactly you got stuck. It's as if you didn't even try.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the other way round: block everything and only allow specific services. In this example, your `eth0` is configured with the `192.168.0.1`, and the other two interfaces are used for the public services.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,22,2083,2087 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ! eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```